# Angular Directive Pre Loading

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

Am working with angular and leaflet .

controller:

```
Config.all().then(function (result) {
$scope.config.minZoom =result.minzoom;
});
```

html:

```
 <div id="map"  leaflet-map  zoom="17" min-zoom="{{ config.minzoom }}" ></div>
```

Directive:

```
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
  onMapReady: '&',
   minZoom: '@',
   scrollWheelZoom: '@',
}
```

Problem:
 The minzoom  i am getting from a service problem is leaflet-map directive is loaded before the service call completed .Thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a sample of your project in plunker and give the URL to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bast way it`s get zoom before state whith leaflet-map was loaded. But you can prevent loading map like this:

```
<div id="map" ng-if="config.minzoom"  leaflet-map  zoom="17" min-zoom="{{ config.minzoom }}" ></div>
```